# Converting lowercase letters to uppercase

Tags: c, string, uppercase, lowercase

I have a program to reverse a string and convert it to uppercase. If I write `helloworld!`, the output must be `!DLROWOLLEH`. But if I write `hello world!` the output is `!DLRO`. Could you tell me where the possible problem is?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char * reverse(const char * text)
{

if (text==NULL)
return NULL;

int length = strlen(text);
char * reversed_string = malloc(length+1);

for(int i = 0; i < length/2; ++i)
    {
        reversed_string[i] = text[(length-1) - i];
        reversed_string[(length-1) - i] = text[i];
    }

reversed_string[length] = '\0';

//upper(reversed_string);

return reversed_string;
}




void upper(char *str1)                                          
{
    while(*str1!='\0')                                                   
        {
            if(*str1>96&&*str1<123)                          
                *str1=*str1-32;                                     
        str1++;                                                        
        }
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char p[256];
    fgets(p, sizeof(p), stdin);

    char * rev_str = reverse(p);
    upper(rev_str);
    printf("%s\n", rev_str);

    rev_str = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you really defining `upper()` __inside__ `reverse()`???

Comment: @SouravGhosh It's a gcc extension and hence it's probably valid code, it's a bad idea and it's actually allowed or encouraged by some programming languages, I don't see the use case, But I am scared from programmers who learned it. The apparent reason to do this is that variables local to the external function are visible in the internal one, it's not like you can't pass them as parameters and do whatever you like with them, so using this technique means that there is a problem in understanding structured programming while it's a very complicated **structure**.

Comment: yep,is that big problem ?

Comment: @iharob the last line is what I tried to mean. :-)

Comment: @JakubEliaš It's not standard and it's a bad idea, bad design.

Comment: Ok,guys, I've edited the code,should be ok ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here

```
for(int i = 0; i < length/2; ++i)
```

It `length` is an odd number (like 11 in your example), this will implicitly round down, and as a consequence, you never write to the middle element in the string. Un your case, this happened to be 0, but that is not guaranteed to be so, so any character might have appeared there, instead of terminating the string early.

The easiest fix would be changing that to `(length+1)/2`, but that will have the effect that you write the middle element *twice*.

Actually, I think it is much easier if you just reverse the string just by iterating over it in one direction instead of from both.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your code and it works as expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char * reverse(const char * text)
{

    if (text==NULL)
        return NULL;

    unsigned long length = strlen(text);
    char * reversed_string = malloc(length+1);

    for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        reversed_string[i] = text[(length-1) - i];
        //reversed_string[(length-1) - i] = text[i];
    }

    reversed_string[length] = '\0';

    //upper(reversed_string);

    return reversed_string;
}




void upper(char *str1)
{
    while(*str1!='\0')
    {
        if(*str1>96&&*str1<123)
            *str1=*str1-32;
        str1++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

    char p[256];
    fgets(p, sizeof(p), stdin);

    char * rev_str = reverse(p);
    printf("%s\n", rev_str);
    upper(rev_str);
    printf("%s\n", rev_str);

    rev_str = 0;

    return 0;
}
```